# Apply operation and list to nested list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, iterator

There are a large number of questions on iterating over nested lists, however I would like to iterate over a nested list and apply another list.

Here is my scenario:

```
def operation(a, b):
    return a + b

def magic_function(func, list, nested_list):
    """iterate over nested_list and apply the next element of list"""
    ...

magic_function(operation, [0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
```

---

Desired output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13]]
```

The urge might be strong to answer this with numpy, but in the real scenario, these are objects, not numbers.

The standard `itertools.chain.from_iterable` does not work here, since it does not preserve the nesting of the list.

Comment: Please try it and see how far you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an implementation that works on arbitrarily deeply nested lists:

```
def nested_map(f, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [nested_map(f, item) for item in obj]
    else:
        return f(obj)

def magic_function(func, seq, nested_list):
    g = iter(seq)
    return nested_map(lambda item: func(item, next(g)), nested_list)

def operation(a, b):
    return a + b

result = magic_function(operation, [0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, [[3]]]])
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, [[13]]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.count` to index your flat list:

```
from itertools import count

def operation(a, b):
    return a + b

def foo(func, lst, nested_list):
    idx = count()
    res = [[operation(j, lst[next(idx)]) for j in i] for i in nested_list]
    return res

res = foo(operation, [0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13]]
```

Or you can iterate the flat list directly:

```
def foo(func, lst, nested_list):
    k = iter(lst)
    res = [[operation(j, next(k)) for j in i] for i in nested_list]
    return res
```

Comment: But does this work on arbitrarily deeply nested lists? Would it work on `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, [3]]]`, for example?

Comment: @Kevin, No, you can use a recursive function for this. It's not clear whether or not your example is applicable to OP's use case.